# How to run LangChain Ollama with ngrok url?

Tags: python, ngrok, large-language-model, ollama

I ran a script to get the ngrok url:

```
import asyncio

# Set LD_LIBRARY_PATH so the system NVIDIA library 
os.environ.update({'LD_LIBRARY_PATH': '/usr/lib64-nvidia'})

async def run_process(cmd):
  print('>>> starting', *cmd)
  p = await asyncio.subprocess.create_subprocess_exec(
      *cmd,
      stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,
      stderr=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,
  )

  async def pipe(lines):
    async for line in lines:
      print(line.strip().decode('utf-8'))

  await asyncio.gather(
      pipe(p.stdout),
      pipe(p.stderr),
  )

await asyncio.gather(
  run_process(['ngrok', 'config', 'add-authtoken','mytoken'])
)

await asyncio.gather(
    run_process(['ollama', 'serve']),
    run_process(['ngrok', 'http', '--log', 'stderr', '11434']),
)
```

After that, I ran the command `export OLLAMA_HOST = url` and `ollama pull llama2` on my MAC terminal.

Finally, I ran the code below using Python:

```
ollama = Ollama(base_url=url, model="llama2")

print(ollama("why is the sky blue"))
```

But it gave the error 404.

I tried to install ngrok on Python and set the auth token and I expected it can connect to the url. But it still gave me 404 error.

Comment: `export OLLAMA_HOST = url` with spaces around the equals sign is not doing what you hope (and I think would be a syntax error in the shells I am familiar with).

Answer (score 0):

I too faced the same issue. still having issue with the ollama server. The server is not responding but able to communicate now. Try to open port `11434` using command `sudo ufw allow tcp/11434` on the ollama hosted machine.If this not work try the following:

```
sudo systemctl stop ollama.service
sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/ollama.service
#add a line Environment under section [Service]:

[Service]
Environment="OLLAMA_HOST=0.0.0.0"

sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart ollama.service
ngrok http --log stderr 11434
```

Now use the Ngrok URL on your code or where you want. But still I am getting error

> raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
> requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))